# Unable to write to keyboard output from microsoft service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Hey im writing an adapter for a USB cardreader that runs as a microsoft service, in that service i'm trying to write to keyboard output (with Console.WriteLine("Some text") or SendKeys.Send("Some text")) so that any window in focus will write something as if you where typing some keys on the keyboard. But i think that the microsoft service doesn't have the correct user context so that i can't access the correct register for keyboard output or else i have the wrong stdoutput (which i believe can be overvriden), i know that the standard output for console applications is the console but what is the standard output for a microsoft service and how can i direct the standard output to the keyboard output ???

Comment: [`Console.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1) does **not** write as if you were typing some keys. You might want to check out [how to simulate mouse and keyboard events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-simulate-mouse-and-keyboard-events-in-code)

Comment: Ahh yeah sorry i have also tried with SendKeys() from windows.forms library... And it still doesn't work :-)